# Windows or Linux program to turn a laptop into an HTTP proxy address?

Tags: http, proxy

I have a normal home internet connection.  I would like to be able to run some kind of program or code (in conjunction with setting up my router properly) such that my computer can become a proxy server.

To clarify, I'd like to be able to connect to my home internet IP from anywhere, by using an http proxy.  So wherever I am, I can simply input my proxy address and password into the browser settings for http proxies, and all my traffic would rout through my home internet.

I don't want to VPN or remote desktop into my home computer.  I have used proxy services in the past and they work alright, but I'd much prefer to have my own personalized proxy which is not being shared by other users.  How would I go about doing this?  Is there some software or coding instructions to turn a computer/router into a proxy which can be accessed elsewhere?

I use windows but could potentially use linux if it the only option for this sort of thing.  Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck using a Raspberry Pi for this.

Answer (score 1):

Linksys has a few routers that include an OpenVPN Server. The setup also requires downloading an OpenVPN Client.

Answer (score 0):

Linux isn't the only option, but certainly the least expensive, quickest and easiest.

I do what you are wanting to do with a Pi at the house and a single port forwarded, where SSH is listening.  I connect to it using the `-D` option, which turns the SSH connection into a dynamic SOCKS5 proxy over the encrypted connection.  Connection can be established from `ssh` on Mac or other *nix, or via Putty on Windows.